# fetchCol on collection returning same values

Tags: collection, zend-framework

I'm attempting to retrieve the entire column of both `kit_sku` and `related_sku`.  However, it doesn't seem to parse correctly.  Both `$componentSkus` and `$componentRequiredQuantity` are returning identical arrays.

```
        $kitCollection = Mage::getModel('path/path')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('kit_sku', $sku)
            ->setOrder('related_sku', 'ASC');

        $select = $kitCollection->getSelect();

        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->distinct()
            ->columns('related_sku')
            ->columns('required_quantity');

        $connection = $kitCollection->getConnection();

        $componentSkus = $connection->fetchCol($select, 0);

        $componentRequiredQuantity = $connection->fetchCol($select, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html fetchCol will only return the first column.

Your best bet will be to use fetchPairs and then use PHP's array_keys to get the first column and array_values for second.

Or do 2 separate queries

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any `fetchCol()` implementation that takes the column index as second argument. It always

> Fetches the first column of all SQL result rows as an array.

You should have a look at the database adapter class and find another `fetch*()` method appropriate to your needs.